# processing camera frames in vuforia SDK

Tags: android, image-processing, vuforia

i want color of some pixels in RGB image of every camera frame in Vuforia, but according to [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/android-how-can-i-access-camera-image) just one byte keeps all of data about each pixels, am i right?
so how can i get color of each pixel?
thanks in advance

Comment: RGB565 uses  two bytes per pixel; 5 bits red, 6 bits green and 5 bits for blue. RGB888 three bytes per pixel; 8 bits for each colour. Guess this sample you linked to prints out the first byte only as an example.

Comment: you mean in RGB565 type the first byte contains red and some part of green data?@harism

Comment: If the image format is RGB565 then yes.

Comment: If you check the C/C++ example lower on the page, they create buffer for storing image data using _env->NewByteArray(numPixels * 2)_ . Ie. two bytes per pixel. I see no reason why the new Java API wouldn't work the same way.